# android: how to create a list of most used applications

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm building a launcher app and i want to make a button show my most used applications.
I can get the String of the package name of an app every time it's being open.
How can i get the most used apps into a list or at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a STICKY Service which checks current running apps at a set interval and then use that to determine the Apps that are most used.